# To which set belongs this door with stickers on both sides?

Tags: part-identification

I try to identify sets in a large bag of unsorted Lego (will probably have to ask some more of these in the coming days).

This piece is a real odd-ball: A black door with (mostly silver) stickers on both sides. I'm not sure if the door-frame goes with it, because they were separated in the bag, but it is the only door-frame in the whole bag.
The frame looks almost white, but it is actually grey. The shiny silver really messed up the white-balance of the camera.

[image: Side 1][image: Side 2]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stickered part is [57895pb056](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=57895pb056#C=11) which only appears in [set 75954 "Hogwarts Great Hall"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75954-1):

[image: 75954]

Comment: That appears to be the one.. Unfortunately my large bag of unsorted stuff doesn't have anything else from that set....

Comment: As a counterpoint, I have bought this set used, and after taking it apart and going through the entire BrickLink inventory, I've discovered that it's the one piece that's missing. So perhaps it's mine!

Comment: Who knows? I got this bag in The Netherlands. Is that anywhere near you?

Comment: @RSchulz : did you mean to put beta links in your answer ? They don't appear to be fully functional (doesn't actually show that the part is in that set for me [eg.](https://www.bricklink.com/r3/catalog/appears_in.page?idItem=176327&idColor=11)).

Comment: @SanderDeDycker The link to the set on that brinklink parts-page seems empty indeed. But the 2nd link (and the image above) are clear enough.

Comment: For clarification : my comment wasn't intended to cast doubt on the correctness of the answer (it's correct and I upvoted), but rather to suggest using the regular non-beta links in order to avoid confusion - unless there's a reason to use the beta links.

Comment: @Tonny I can categorically deny ever buying used Lego in the Netherlands.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker I only shared what BrickLink seemed to want me to see. I also had trouble with the set list being empty, but had just assumed it was a compatibility issue with my browser or some such, not with BL itself.

Comment: @RSchulz: I've submitted an edit that switches to the classic links. Feel free to disapprove/revert if that's not desired. For info - all the way at the bottom of the bricklink pages, you should have a link available to switch to the classic view if you ever need it. I'll clean up my comments here as soon as they're no longer relevant.

Comment: I wouldn't delete anything - everyone can look back on this (hopefully brief) time when BL was a bit messed up.